# Unable to append string to mutable array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, append

**Context** - I'm currently learning Swift `Struct`. So I decided to create my own Phone structure in Playground. (see below)

**Problem** - 
The `downloadApp` method on the `phone` struct is throwing the following error.. `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`.

**Expect outcome** - To peacefully append new strings to my `apps` property, which is an array of strings.

**Swift code**

```
struct Phone {
    let capacity : Int
    let Brand : Sting
    var name: String
    let model: String
    var apps: [String]
    var contacts: [String]

    var formatCapacity: String {
        return "\(capacity)GB"
    }

    func downloadApp(name: String){
        apps.append(name) // ERROR 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to mark `downloadApp` as `mutating`. The issue is caused by the fact that `downloadApp` is declared in a `struct` type, which is a value type and hence if you mutate any properties (namely, the `apps` array here) of the struct, you actually mutate the struct itself. By marking the function as `mutating`, the compiler allows such modification of the struct through a member function of the type.

```
mutating func downloadApp(name: String){
    apps.append(name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Apples Intro to app development book didn't show me that! Baby steps I guess